# How to get json data from react fetch method

Tags: reactjs, json, fetch-api

I am unable to get data form API. I tried different way, but no luck. Here is my Code and API. I want to use these data (JSON) through react fetch method.

```js
// My Fetch API

fetchData() {
        fetch('MYAPI_URL')
       .then(response => response.json())
        
  // .then(parsedJSON => console.log(parsedJSON)) //prints the data on console 
//        .then(parsedJSON => console.log(parsedJSON.status)) // Not Worked
  //      .then(parsedJSON => console.log(parsedJSON.data.Products) )  // Not Worked
      .then(parsedJSON => console.log(parsedJSON.status.data) ) // not working. 

  .then(parsedJSON => parsedJSON.data.map(pro => (
            {
      ..... Other code ....
      }
      ))

   }
    
    
// below is my api data

  "status": true,
  "data": {
    "banner": "mydomain.com/img/img1.png",
    "Products": [
      {
        "CategoryCode": "03",
        "CategoryName": "Appetizers",
        "SubCategory": [
          {
            "SubCategoryCode": "038",
            "SubCategoryName": "Chicken Wings",
            "Image":     "banner": "mydomain.com/img/img1.png",
            "SubCategoryType": [
              {
                "TypeCode": "05",
                "TypeName": "Normal",
                "AdditionalPrice": "0",
                "TypeSize": [
                  {
                    "SizeCode": "17",
                    "SizeName": "6 Pcs",
                    "Description": "Oven baked hot and spicy chicken wings.",
                    "Price": "349",
                    "Toppings": [
                      
                    ]
                   }
                ]
              }
             ]
             ...............



// I want to get Products Code etc. But I can't. No idea where I am doing wrong
```

When I use this fetch api it was working. The data was almost same with the above one, but that was not real Rest API.

Comment: Please specify "it is not working". Does the API endpoint not return any data or a HTTP error, is the response not properly present in react afterwards?

Comment: `.then(parsedJSON => console.log(parsedJSON))` this line works right?

Comment: Yes it prints data.

Comment: 1.  .then(parsedJSON => console.log(parsedJSON.status))  

2.  .then(parsedJSON => console.log(parsedJSON.status.data))

3.  .then(parsedJSON => console.log(parsedJSON.data))

All these lines says that ...map is not a function. and In Console.log it prints undifined

Comment: @Capricorn can you please look into this

Answer (score -1):

1. If you need to just receive the data and NOT update React component (not storing in local state), you can have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44644532/1263904
2. Otherwise check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50980558/1263904

Comment: Just Suppose that if I have to get data from the above api, how to do this in fetch api.

Comment: Have you even looked over the links?