# Unable to add Async keyword with App.tsx in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-18

We have an ReactJS App, and want to validate saved JWT Token at API end. For that adding await axiosClient.post("${URL}/AuthenticateUser/ValidateToken") in App.tsx, it's throwing an error.

**index.tsx:**

```
const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container!);

root.render(
  <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
    <App />
  </MsalProvider>,
);

module.hot?.accept();
```

**App.tsx:**

```
async function App() {
let isAuthenticated = false;
  const url = `${URL}/AuthenticateUser/ValidateToken`;

  if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
    await axiosClient.post(url).then((result) => {
      /* Do Something */
    });
}
```

**axiosClient.tsx:**

```
export const axiosClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: URL,
  timeout: 300000,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${getToken()}`,
  },
});
```

[image]

**Error:**

```
TS2786: 'App' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its return type 'Promise<Element>' is not a valid JSX element.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await inside a React functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57847626/using-async-await-inside-a-react-functional-component)

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980378/fetching-data-in-react) or [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) or...

Comment: @JaredSmith 300000 milliseconds is 5 minutes

Comment: Refer below answer, that seems similar to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57847626/using-async-await-inside-a-react-functional-component

Comment: @JaredSmith

Now we are getting below error. Error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Comment: @AnkitJain Are you calling a hook inside a conditional or a callback? Do you have an early return in your function component with a hook call after it?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be adding the async keyword to the React component itself. Instead you should do something like this

```
function App() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const getToken = async () => {
      const url = `${URL}/AuthenticateUser/ValidateToken`;

      if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
        await axiosClient.post(url).then(result => {
          /* Do Something */

          //Set this wherever you need it
          setIsAuthenticated(true);
        });
      }
    };
    getToken();
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Now we are getting below error. Error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Comment: Can you show the code?